Is there any way to list all the custom events without broken down by hour in facebook ads
Is there any way to list all the custom events without broken down by hour
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ads-pixel/stats/v19.0
It only returned custom events that happened within 28 days. How to overcome this limitation.
I need a list of all custom events. Is there any API to get that
